# Search arraylist for keyword

Tags: c#

Is there any way to search an arraylist storing a line as a string? I want to search by the first word in every line stored in the arraylist. I tried doing the Arraylist.Contains() and Arraylist.IndexOf but those do not seem to be working? Anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using an `ArrayList` or an `array` or a `List<T>`?

Comment: If possible switch to List<T>. It will reduce casting.

Comment: you're using an arraylist because you have to or because you don't know any better?

Comment: i did not know there was an alternative way to declare a collection of objects without specifying a static size for the structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string[] matches = arrayList.Cast<string>()
                            .Where(i => i.StartsWith(searchTerm)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you will need to look at each item in the list and decide if the line matches your condition.

So, in pseudo-code:

```
for each line in listOfLines
    if line StartsWith "some string"
        // It's a match!
    end if
end loop
```

C#'s `String` class has a great [`StartsWith`](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.startswith.aspx&ei=isf3TZfJDJGAhQeusI2iDA&usg=AFQjCNE8op_9MtJrQDParmgUMeZCiQBbBA) method you could use. How you loop through the list will of course depend on the type of list you have, but as `ArrayList` appears to implement `IList`, which implements `IEnumerable`, then you should have no problem using a `foreach(var item in list)` type construct to build the loop.

Answer (score 0):

For one, you want to use `List<string>` (System.Collections.Generic) instead of `ArrayList` so you can have a strongly-typed list of strings rather than a weakly typed list of objects.

Secondly, no, `ArrayList.Contains` and `ArrayList.IndexOf` would perform full object matches, they are not performing partials.

Thirdly, the methodology is going to the same as the answer to [your question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6279503/c-searching-for-a-keyword-in-a-txt-file). As in, looping over the values contained, and checking each individual string. You could write that to use Linq, but the idea is the same.

Comment: what is the difference between strongly typed and weakly typed? Im new to c# so ive never heard of List<>

Comment: `ArrayList` stores everything as an `object`. There are no protections in place, you could add anything to it. A string, an integer, an object of type `Foo`, anything. A generic `List<T>` is going to restrict all inputs to type `T` (`T` being a placeholder, ergo, `List<string>`). Adding and retrieving items from the list is all done in type `T`. For value types, there's less boxing. For other types, there's no need to cast going in or out.

Comment: @Dominique, for more on ArrayList vs `List<T>`, I suggest [starting here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3530350/what-is-difference-b-w-generic-list-and-arraylist-generic-list-vs-hashtable-gen).

Answer (score 0):

Why not just this

```
var results = from string x in arrayList where x.StartsWith(query);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Collections;
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        ArrayList arraylist =new ArrayList();
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            arraylist.Add("This is line1");
            arraylist.Add("Jack is good boy");
            arraylist.Add("Azak is a child");
            arraylist.Add("Mary has a chocolate");
            MessageBox.Show(GetSentenceFromFirstChar('J'));

        }
        public string GetSentenceFromFirstChar(char firstcharacter)
        {
            bool find=false;
            int index=-1;
            for (int i = 0; i < arraylist.Count; i++)
            {
                if ((char)arraylist[i].ToString()[0] == firstcharacter)
                {
                    index = i;
                    find = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (find)
            {
                return arraylist[index].ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                return "not found";
            }
        }


    }
}
```

maybe helps..