# how do i initialize my arraylist

Tags: vb.net, arraylist

I have a function that adds items to my arraylist. my problem is that it only holds one item at a time since it is reinitializing the array lit every time I click my button. what is the syntax  in VB to only initialize the array if it has not been created yet?

```
 Dim itemSelectAs New ArrayList()
 Dim Quantities As New ArrayList()
 Dim itemQtyOrdered As Integer

Public Sub ShtickDataList_ItemCommand(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListViewCommandEventArgs) Handles ShtickDataList.ItemCommand


    If e.CommandName = "addToCart" Then
        Dim itemQuantity As DropDownList = e.Item.FindControl("QuantityDropDown")
        itemQtyOrdered = itemQuantity.SelectedValue
        ItemSelect.Add(e.CommandArgument)
        Quantities.Add(itemQtyOrdered)

        Session("itemInCart") = ItemSelect
        Session("quantities") = Quantities


        viewInvoice()

    End If


End Sub

Protected Sub viewInvoice()

    Dim itemSelected As ArrayList = DirectCast(Session("itemInCart"), ArrayList)
    Dim QuantityofItem As ArrayList = DirectCast(Session("quantities"), ArrayList)

    Dim conn As SqlConnection
    Dim comm As SqlCommand
    Dim reader As SqlDataReader
    Dim purimConnection2 As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Purim").ConnectionString
    conn = New SqlConnection(purimConnection2)

    comm = New SqlCommand("SELECT ProductName FROM Products WHERE ProductID = @ProductID", conn)

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To ItemSelect.Count - 1
    comm.Parameters.Add("@ProductID", Data.SqlDbType.Int)
    comm.Parameters("@ProductID").Value = (ItemSelected.Count - 1)

    'Next

    Try
        conn.Open()
        reader = comm.ExecuteReader()
        ViewCartlink.Text = "View Cart: (" & ItemSelected.Count & ")"



    Finally
        conn.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: I want to keep adding thingsto the array list. that way I have beeen doing is this is with myArrayList.Add. Each time I click the putton to add an item to the arraylist the last item overides the first leaving me with one item in the arraylist at anygiven point. I want to successfully addd items to my arraylist to be availabe in the users session. someone mentioned the fact that if myst be initializing the array list over again thereby losing the first item

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you want to avoid Generic.List(Of T)? See [What is difference b/w Generic List and Arraylist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3530350/what-is-difference-b-w-generic-list-and-arraylist-generic-list-vs-hashtable-ge) and [ArrayList’s vs. generic List for primitive types and 64-bits](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joshwil/archive/2004/04/13/112598.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

First you need to dimension your array list.

```
 Dim array_list as ArrayList()
```

Then you can instantiate one

```
 array_list = new ArrayList
```

Or you can combine it into one step:

```
 Dim array_list = new ArrayList()
```

After that you can add and remove elements from your array list with

```
 array_list.add(obj)
```

and remove with

```
 array_list.remove(obj)
```

It looks like your problem is related to accessing the members of an arraylist. New items are always added to the end of an arraylist. To access them directly, you will need their index. If you know the index of the item you want to access use

```
 array_list(i)
```

If you don't you will need to iterate over the array. To do this you have two options. You can use "for each" or you can use a normal for loop and use array_list.count as your upper bound.

You're recreating your two session values every time you call your button click menu. You need to pull them out of the Session variable and put them in local variables and put them back into the session variable.

Your button method should be:

```
 Public Sub ShtickDataList_ItemCommand(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListViewCommandEventArgs) Handles ShtickDataList.ItemCommand


   if isNothing(itemSelect) Then itemSelect = New ArrayList()
   if isNothing(itemQtyOrdered) Then itemQtyOrdered= New ArrayList()

   If e.CommandName = "addToCart" Then


       Dim itemQuantity As DropDownList = e.Item.FindControl("QuantityDropDown")
       itemQtyOrdered = itemQuantity.SelectedValue
       ItemSelect.Add(e.CommandArgument)
       Quantities.Add(itemQtyOrdered)

       Session("itemInCart") = ItemSelect
       Session("quantities") = Quantities


       viewInvoice()

   End If


 End Sub
```

And change your Global calls to:

```
 Dim itemSelect As ArrayList() = Session("itemInCart")
 Dim Quantities As New ArrayList() = Session("quantities")
```

Comment: so I have been doing that. but the first item get lost when I add the new item

Comment: how are you adding to the arraylist? How are you accessing the members of it?

Comment: where are you defining the arraylist?

Comment: how are you accessing it's members?

Comment: sorry - im not sure what u mean by that

Comment: @user2120280 I want to know how you know that .add is overwriting the members of your arraylist. And yes, please add some code to your question so we can get a better handle on what you're really asking.

Comment: @user2120280 we just need the relevant portions. And edit them into your question. Specifically, how you are accessing the members of the arraylist

Comment: i added it to the origional question

Comment: @user2120280 I think I found your issue.

Comment: you're adding count - 1 as the @productId. is that intentional or do you want the value of the array list object?

Comment: can you print the count to a debug line? does it increment when you hit the button?

Comment: that was wrong. I did have what you said all along I mustve typed it over wrong here

Comment: it increments - goes to one and the next time it stays at one

Comment: You need to instantiate it from your session variable each time you call the ShtickDataList_ItemCommand method. You're effectively recreating it each time you call that method.

Comment: ok, make sence. can you help me out with that? how do I rite it? whats the correct syntax

Comment: Added what I think the function should look like.

Comment: thanks- the lap top I was working on died and i dont have the charger. I will do thid a little later and let u know how it went

Comment: just saw that your code formatting was wonked and the arraylists are globals. Instantiate those globals with = Session("xyz").

Comment: Just edited again. Change the initialization of your globals to reference the Session variables.

Comment: no, leave that part in, take out the instantiation of the arrayLists and do that on the globals. What's happening is you are overwriting your session variables with teh globals each time it postsback.

Comment: yes. Replace ItemSelect and Quantities with the last 2 lines of my answer. And the function with the one I've got for you.

Answer (score 2):

Define your array outside the button click event.  (Form level)

Then in the button click event try this:

```
If myArrayList Is Nothing then
   'initializes the array list only if that hasn't happened yet
   myArrayList = new ArrayList
End If
'adds the item to the existing list without causing it to reintialize
myArrayList.add(item)
```

That way it is initialized if it hasn't been, but not if it already has.  If it is initialized  at the form level ie... its declared as new already then you can just add to it.

Basically make sure that you aren't calling New for the arrayList in the button click event.

Editing for web form:

You should probably check where you initialize your arrayList.  Like in the Page_Load:

```
If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
  myArrayList = New ArrayList
End If
```

[MSDN Postback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback.aspx)

Comment: If it was initialized at the form level, the problem is gone, as far as I understand the question.

Comment: Edited, I said that badly in the answer

Comment: can i write 
If myArrayList Is Nothing then
   myArrayList = new ArrayList
End If
some function()
and ill put the rest in a sep sub

Comment: Yes, exactly.  If it is nothing call new. Then do whatever else you need to do.

Comment: I just saw your question update.  This doesn't apply the same way to the web.  Since you have to deal with session and view state.  You may simply need to only initialize your list if it isn't postback